# C++ convert std::string that contains binary data to char*

Tags: c++, string, base64

Okay, so I'm having a little bit of a problem here.

What I'm doing is converting a binary file (in this example I used a .exe file) to a Base64 string and then converting this one back to binary data to write it to the disk.

So far so good, this code works:

```
std::string str = base64_decode(base64str); // base64str is the base64 string made of the actual .exe file
std::ofstream strm("file.exe", std::ios::binary);
strm << str;
strm.close();
```

The file "file.exe" is being created as expected and I can run it.

Now my problem is that I need the decrypted file as **char*** instead of std::string, but whenever I call this code

```
str.c_str();
```

to either convert it to const char* or char* the contents suddenly no longer equal the binary data contained in **str**, but rather this:

```
MZP
```

So, for instance the following code

```
std::string str = base64_decode(base64str);
std::ofstream strm("file.exe", std::ios::binary);
char* cstr = new char[str.length()-1];
strcpy(cstr, str.c_str());
strm << cstr;
strm.close();
```

would create file.exe, but this time it would contain "MZP" instead of the actual binary data

I have no clue on how to fix this. Of course the char* is mandatory.

Can any of you help?

Comment: `strcpy(cstr, str.c_str());` will stop copying after hitting the first null byte, of which there are probably hundreds in your binary file.

Comment: Don't use `strm << cstr` it will stop at the first null. Use `strm.write()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::string::c_str()` returns a "C string", which is a NUL-terminated array of characters.  Your binary data certainly has NUL terminators in it, prior to the end of the data. This is why your data appears truncated. (Look in a hex editor, I bet byte 0x03 is zero.)

For that reason, you should instead use [`std::basic_string::data`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) to get a pointer to the raw data contained by the string.  When  copying or writing this data, you'll want to not use `strcpy` (which stops at a NUL byte), but rather `memcpy`, or similar.  The size of the data contained by the string can be gotten from [`std::basic_string::size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size).

Comment: Okay, I now have
`std::basic_string<char> dec = base64_decode(base64str);
    char* cdec = new char[dec.size()];
    memcpy(cdec, dec.data(), dec.size());`
Though, it still outputs "MZP" :/

Comment: NOTE: I just tested it, dec.data() also seems to output "MZP"

Comment: NOTE2: dec.data() seems to work fine after changing `stm << cdec` to `strm.write(dec.data(), dec.size())`, but `strm.write(cdec, sizeof(cdec))` still does not work ("MZP" thing)

Comment: `cdec` is a `char*`. `sizeof(char*)` is 4. Use `dec.size()` instead of `sizeof(cdec)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the data inside a `std::string` as a `char*`, you can just grab it. Either:

```
std::string s = ...

char* c1 = &s[0];
char* c2 = const_cast<char*>(s.c_str());
char* c3 = &s.front();
```